# Q: KDE Kalendar - How to connect to/import Outlook calendar?

Tags: kde-plasma

Today, as the date of writing this question, Kalendar got it's first stable (and presumably matrure) update of version 1.0. I have the following question:

At work I have 2 Microsoft accounts. Both have the Calendar integrated into MS Teams. How do you connect to those 2 accounts, in order to show the meetings in the Kalendar application?

System info:

OS: Arch (with KDE Unstable)

Kalendar Version: 1.0.0-1

Environment: KDE